# Validar campos com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Preciso validar alguns campos em tempo de execução, pra que a soma deles não ultrapasse 100%. Já consegui fazer a verificação caso o valor pra distribuir seja 0, ou seja, o cara não pode preencher nenhum valor nos campos nessa situação.

Veja a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

0 campo que identifica o valor "R$100.000,00" é a base para as TextBox, o total de todas as TextBox não pode ultrapassar 100%, no caso da imagem, já atingiu 100% pois existem 2 campos, cada um deles consumindo 50% do total.

O tópico consiste em ajudar pra que quando o cara preencha os campos e o total for igual a 100, não permite preencher mais nenhum campo, se por acaso, o valor pra distribuir for 200 por exemplo e o cara colocar em um dos campos 500, retornar msg de erro até que seja corrigido.

Meu JavaScript:

```
function PreencherPorcentagem(campo){
if (campo.value === "") {
    return;
}

var porcentagem = 0;
var idCampo = campo.id
var idPadrao = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rpPratifAcis_';//parte do id que sempre se repete na grid                       

var fields = idCampo.replace(idPadrao,"").split('_');//array para separar segunda parte do id. Ex: ctl03_txtClienteAgro
var idPrincipal = fields[0];//id único do campo
var nomeCampo = fields[1];                                  

var valorCampo = parseFloat(document.getElementById(campo.id).value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));

//Caso entre na function, altera hidden field para true para separar linhas alteradas na hora de validar método de salvar
document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_hdLinhaAlterada').value = true;

if (idCampo.indexOf('Cliente') != -1) {

    var valorClienteSge = 0;               
    valorClienteSge = parseFloat(document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_hdClienteSge').value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));

    if ((valorClienteSge === 0 && valorCampo === 0) || valorCampo === 0) {
        porcentagem = 0;
    }
    else if (valorClienteSge === 0 && valorCampo !== 0) {
        alert("Porcentagem não pode ser maior que 100%.");
        document.getElementById(campo.id).value = ""
        return;
    }
    else {
        porcentagem = ((valorCampo / valorClienteSge) * 100);
    }                                             

}
else if (idCampo.indexOf('Recurso') != -1) {

    var valorRecursoSge = 0;
    valorRecursoSge = parseFloat(document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_hdRecursoSge').value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(",00", ""));

    if ((valorRecursoSge === 0 && valorCampo === 0) || valorCampo === 0) {
        porcentagem = 0;
    }
    else if (valorRecursoSge === 0 && valorCampo !== 0) {
        alert("Porcentagem não pode ser maior que 100%.");
        document.getElementById(campo.id).value = ""
        return;
    }
    else {
        porcentagem = ((valorCampo / valorRecursoSge) * 100);
    }

}

//Preenche o campo da porcentagem
porcentagem = (Math.floor(porcentagem * 100) / 100);
document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + "_"+  nomeCampo.replace("txt", "txtPorcentagem")).setAttribute("value", porcentagem.toString().replace(".", ",") + "%");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi assim xD :

```js
function PreencherPorcentagem(campo) {

            if (campo.value === "") {
                return;
            }

            var porcentagem = 0;
            var idCampo = campo.id
            var idPadrao = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rpPratifAcis_';//parte do id que sempre se repete na grid                       

            var fields = idCampo.replace(idPadrao, "").split('_');//array para separar segunda parte do id. Ex: ctl03_txtClienteAgro
            var idPrincipal = fields[0];//id único do campo
            var nomeCampo = fields[1];

            var valorCampo = parseFloat(document.getElementById(campo.id).value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));

            //Caso entre na function, altera hidden field para true para separar linhas alteradas na hora de validar método de salvar
            document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_hdLinhaAlterada').value = true;


            if (idCampo.indexOf('Cliente') != -1) {

                var valorClienteSge = 0;
                valorClienteSge = parseFloat(document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_hdClienteSge').value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));

                var A = document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_txtClienteAgro');
                var B = document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_txtClienteComercio');
                var C = document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_txtClienteIndustria');
                var D = document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_txtClienteServico');

                var valorClienteAgro        = parseFloat(A.value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));
                var valorClienteComercio    = parseFloat(B.value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));
                var valorClienteIndustria   = parseFloat(C.value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));
                var valorClienteServico     = parseFloat(D.value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));
                
                if ((valorClienteSge === 0 && valorCampo === 0) || valorCampo === 0) {
                    porcentagem = 0;
                }
                else if ((valorClienteAgro + valorClienteComercio + valorClienteIndustria + valorClienteServico) > valorClienteSge) {
                    alert("O valor preenchido não pode ser superior ao valor disponível.");

                    A.style.borderColor = "red";
                    B.style.borderColor = "red";
                    C.style.borderColor = "red";
                    D.style.borderColor = "red";
                }
                else if (valorClienteSge === 0 && valorCampo !== 0) {
                    alert("Porcentagem não pode ser maior que 100%.");
                    document.getElementById(campo.id).value = ""

                    return document.getElementById("myInput").style.backgroundColor = "Red";
                }
                else if (valorRecursoSge === 0 && valorCampo !== 0) {
                    document.getElementById(campo.id).value = ""

                    return document.getElementById("myInput").style.backgroundColor = "Red";
                } else {
                    porcentagem = ((valorCampo / valorClienteSge) * 100);
                }

            }
            else if (idCampo.indexOf('Recurso') != -1) {

                var valorRecursoSge = 0;
                valorRecursoSge = parseFloat(document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_hdRecursoSge').value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(",00", ""));

                var Um      = document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_txtRecursoAgro');
                var Dois    = document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_txtRecursoComercio');
                var Tres    = document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_txtRecursoIndustria');
                var Quatro  = document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + '_txtRecursoServico');

                var valorRecursoAgro        = parseFloat(Um.value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));
                var valorRecursoComercio    = parseFloat(Dois.value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));
                var valorRecursoIndustria   = parseFloat(Tres.value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));
                var valorRecursoServico     = parseFloat(Quatro.value.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace(".", ""));

                

                
                if((valorRecursoSge === 0 && valorCampo === 0) || valorCampo === 0) {
                    porcentagem = 0;
                }
                else if ((valorRecursoAgro + valorRecursoComercio + valorRecursoIndustria + valorRecursoServico) > valorRecursoSge) {
                    alert("O valor preenchido não pode ser superior ao valor disponível.");

                    Um.style.borderColor = "red";
                    Dois.style.borderColor = "red";
                    Tres.style.borderColor = "red";
                    Quatro.style.borderColor = "red";
                }
                else if (valorRecursoSge === 0 && valorCampo !== 0) {
                    alert("Porcentagem não pode ser maior que 100%.");
                    return document.getElementById(campo.id).value = ""
                    document.getElementById("myInput").style.backgroundColor = "Red";
                }
                else {
                    porcentagem = ((valorCampo / valorRecursoSge) * 100);
                }

            }


            //Preenche o campo da porcentagem
            porcentagem = (Math.floor(porcentagem * 100) / 100);
            document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + "_" + nomeCampo.replace("txt", "txtPorcentagem")).setAttribute("value", porcentagem.toString().replace(".", ",") + "%");
        
            //Preenche o campo da porcentagem
            porcentagem = (Math.floor(porcentagem * 100) / 100);
            document.getElementById(idPadrao + idPrincipal + "_" + nomeCampo.replace("txt", "txtPorcentagem")).setAttribute("value", porcentagem.toString().replace(".", ",") + "%");
        }
```